# Google drive v2 api sample

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I need to write sample code
I need to allow user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com, user3@gmail.com,... access to all my files(**my_mail@gmail.com**) in google drive account using sdk.
I tried this(install application on google developers console), and the service returns the files of user which login in browser in current time

```
ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
    ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET,
};

IDataStore StoredRefreshToken = new SavedDataStore(new StoredResponse() { });
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets,
        SCOPES, "1", CancellationToken.None, StoredRefreshToken /*, credentialPersistanceStore*/).Result;

BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = APP_USER_AGENT
};

return new DriveService(initializer);
```

I write on asp.net mvc, hope you are hepls

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @jon i think he's asking how to login using a specific user, instead of the currently logged in user in a browser on the machine.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I'm not sure of the best way to do that :(

Comment: yes, i need to acceess google drive files on my account other user(s)

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to store a refresh token for my_mail@gmail.com and then use that to generate an access token. You can use the steps at [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical/19766913#19766913) which means you don't need to write any authorisation code.

Comment: ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets
{ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET,
};IDataStore StoredRefreshToken = new SavedDataStore(new StoredResponse() { });
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets,
SCOPES, "1", CancellationToken.None, StoredRefreshToken /*, credentialPersistanceStore*/).Result;
BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
{HttpClientInitializer = credential,
ApplicationName = APP_USER_AGENT
};var service = DriveService(initializer);

Comment: FileList files = service.Files.List().Execute();return files.Items.Count; and this return the count files in current logged user in browser, and i need a only my files without loggin in account in browser

Comment: All of the Google sample code is for a conventional user authorising access to how own resources. You can't copy paste it as your use case is different. You will need to research the Google OAuth SDK to figure out how to get it to use your stored refresh token. Or stop using it and simple call the OAuth the endpoint yourself. It's described here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh